# l need to visit Website on a LAN,how to set jdbc url?

Tags: spring-boot, jdbc

l have a local Web project,when l visit this Web project on a LAN,how to set my jdbc url.
For example,my project is deploy on computer which ip is 192.168.1.126.In my springboot configuration,my jdbc url is http://localhost:xxx.When l use a computer on a LAN to visit this website,springboot can connect mysql conrrectly.But how does it realize connecting with 192.168.1.126,not visiting computer.